# Where should I put my code in ActionBar.TabListener

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview

I have just started with an ActionBar.TabListener with 3 tabs.
I selected new "Tabbed activity" in Android Studio.
My activity is called test...not the best name but I'm just trying to learn:)

I have a listView in fragment_test.xml that I want to fill with data after a raw sql search.
If I put this code in onCreateView then everytime I click on a tab it will re-write that tab with the same info in the listView.
What I want is to have diffrent information in those tabs.... then I need to know which tab that is clicked. That I did with mViewPager.getCurrentItem() ....Is this right? How can i get the name of the tab instead?

I have also found onTabSelected...should I put my code here? In this case I think I know which tab that is selected but is it really wise to put the code here?
If I do this then listView1 becomes null...why?:

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        listAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.simplerow, testArray);
        listAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView1.setAdapter(listAdapter2);
```

---

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to load `Fragment`'s `ListView` according to `Tab`'s selected position.

If that's the case, you should not modify `Fragment`'s `ListView` in `Activity`. Instead, pass Tab's selected position to `Fragment` as an argument from `Activity` and  load `ListView` in `Fragment` according to that position.